# firefox 73 How to fix netflix F7702-1003 error? "the plugin has crashed"

Tags: flash, netflix

I recently updated firefox to version 73. Netflix stopped working then. When I try to start the movie I get the error F7702-1003, and at the top I see the message "the plugin has crashed". After checking the console log, I found one error "uncaught exception: Object" and a lot of warnings "unreachable code after return statement". In this situation, Netflix recommends restarting the computer, but it does nothing. I also tried to refresh firefox without result.

Comment: What Operating System?

Comment: I've encountered the same problem just now. OS: GNU/Linux. (Arch Linux) @DavidPostill

Comment: @InterestingKnox For Linux see [How to Play Netflix on Firefox in Linux](https://itsfoss.com/netflix-firefox-linux/) which discusses this error and tells you how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ive just encountered this problem on my laptop running arch. Seems to be a glibc problem, starting from version 2.31 and not a firefox issue. Downgrading glibc to version 2.30 fixes the problem for now.

See [[SOLVED] Was "Kernel 5.5.2 breaks DRM", should be glibc 2.31 breaks it](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=252706) on Arch forums for more information.

edit: Firefox update to version 73.0.1 fixes the problem, so safe to upgrade glibc to latest version as well.